# How to display an image in full when the image is clicked?

Tags: java, android, image

How to display images in full screen from MYSL when the image icon is clicked? Using JSON and intent. 
**Example Image:**
   [image: Example]

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```java
Uri uri;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    uri = Uri.parse("image_route");
} else {
    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("image_route"));
}
String mime = "*/*";
MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
if (mimeTypeMap.hasExtension(
        mimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString())))
        mime = mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(
              mimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString()));
intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
```

Comment: Can you provide a little explanation with your code so it's more helpful to future visitors?